Weird curve shape in curve data
I was modeling a simple ladder by creating a plane and adding some loop cut,and then I deleted only its phase and convet it into curve,but when I tride to give it some depth in 3d shape.
This happended, the size of depth does't match.

So I tried 2D shape,but it eventually deleted the top of my ladder.

I've been googling this problem for a hour and I still haven't a solution.

Curves cannot branch, i.e. a control point can only be connected to a maximum of two segments. So there cannot be T-shaped crossings with a single curve because then points would be connected to three segments, and so you get separated curve elements in the first screenshot. Switching to 2D will reduce the curve two be only 2-dimensional in X and Y direction or, since your object is rotated 90° on X axis, being limited to the X and Z direction, that's why the top is deleted in the second screenshot because it requires a third dimension in Y direction.
